# Android studio: CutomListView gives strange output, it should give firebase data instead. Any solutions?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to android studio developing, although i wanted to make a chat app. Login and Signup using Firebase auth is working well, chat in general too. But i wanted to create a better look and searched for methods on how to make a cutom ListView. But no tutorials showed a method using firebase data, so i desperately tried it on my own. Sadly, it gives me a strange output on my phone. It shows the standard launcher icon in the ImageView, which should be the users profile pic. The one TextView shows some strange output like: com.glowchat.app.DataClass@3012dc4 -> Glowchat is the name of my app. DataClass is a class in my package com.glowchat.app. The second TextView doesn't show any changes, it shows "[Message]" as it should if the change of the text didnt work. I'm sure the following code is complete garbage, but thanks for looking at it and tryingto help me out.

PS: I left the old standard adapter to easily switch between them for testing purposes, so don't get confused by that.

TestserverActivity.java

```java
package com.glowchat.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestserverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button sendbutton;
    private EditText sendmessage;
    private ListView data;

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<DataClass> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<DataClass> adap;

    private DatabaseReference database;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testserver);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        adap = new ArrayAdapter<DataClass>(this, R.layout.datadisplay, R.id.displayname, arrList);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Testserverdata");
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        sendbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.serversendbutton);
        sendmessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serversendmessage);
        data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.serverdata);

        sendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(sendmessage.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                } else {
                    database.push().setValue(sendmessage.getText().toString());

                    sendmessage.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String tmpname = user.getEmail();
                String tmpmessage = string;
                Uri image = user.getPhotoUrl();

                arrList.add(new DataClass(tmpname, tmpmessage, image));

                adap.notifyDataSetChanged();

                data.setAdapter(adap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

ChatAdapter.java

```java
package com.glowchat.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DataClass> arrList;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataClass> arrList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrList = arrList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.datadisplay, parent, false);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

        name.setText(arrList.get(position).getName());
        message.setText(arrList.get(position).getMessage());
        image.setImageURI(arrList.get(position).getImage());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

DataClass.java

```java
package com.glowchat.app;

import android.net.Uri;

public class DataClass {

    String name;
    String message;
    Uri image;

    public DataClass(String name, String message, Uri image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Uri getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Uri image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

---

Firebase JSON Data:

```
{
  "Testserverdata" : {
    "-LdXa2gqdIND7Pk6094N" : "Hello",
    "-LdXbb_1Fvh0jxsC5zYx" : "u4witsit",
    "-LdXblvyFdMW9XMnbYpW" : "jgug",
    "-LdXtP9ZzjL_a4A4Yqqf" : "moin",
    "-LdYDEBP-ikhIyYWnh3r" : "zgxcc",
    "-LdYEwHcWLzUhM9Rjp4y" : "jfufuru",
    "-LdYwkwKkuxm9plle4hZ" : "hcch",
    "-LdZFhvuXuIJIMRSECNO" : "fjdvve",
    "-LdZFjM7DMr9krCGGei4" : "Nsjabwbs",
    "-LdZNpphDsXfG5JDGd1a" : "uxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Basic answer below. Note that you forgot to share the `DataClass` to the question, but instead added your adapter twice.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i edited the post so its now in there

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i can't fix it. Could you try to do so and give me hints, tips or maybe a result? only if you gtot the time ofc.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `/Testserverdata` in your database (as text, **no screenshots**). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done. But the things that are set into the textview aren't those values we have here, neither the LdX... ones nor the "Hello" and so on

Comment: I'm confused. There seems to be a lot of code here that is unrelated to the problem. Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This may require significant effort from your side, but makes it much more likely that we can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the data from Firebase, you are doing this:

```
database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        String tmpname = user.getEmail();
        String tmpmessage = string;
        Uri image = user.getPhotoUrl();

        arrList.add(new DataClass(tmpname, tmpmessage, ));

        adap.notifyDataSetChanged();

        data.setAdapter(adap);
    }
```

In the first line in `onDataChange` you get the value of `dataSnapshot` as a string: `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)`. This means that whatever JSON value or object you may have had in the database, it is converted to a string.

If you have a JSON object, you're more likely looking to do `dataSnapshot.getValue(DataClass.class)`, and then get the right property from the resulting object.

Comment: When i change it to DataClass.class, then it showsme the following error: Incompatible types. java.lang.String | com.glowchat.app.DataClass. maybe i'm too stupid, but i don't get what you mean...